# How to select a row multiple times with different value attached to each one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all rows 3 times with different value attached to each one of them, for example:

MyTable:

```
Name
_____
Tom
John
```

Result:

```
Name   MyValue
_____  _______
Tom    First
Tom    Second
Tom    Third
John   First
John   Second
John   Third
```

Anyone knows how to do it with MySQL?

Comment: Where does `MyValue` come from?

Comment: What is the datasource of "First/Second/Third" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cross join`:

```
select t.name, x.which
from t cross join
     (select 'First' as which union all
      select 'Second' as which union all
      select 'Third' as which
     ) x
```